# SORTING Hierarchical Queries in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression, hierarchical

I have following issue: I have a table for maintaining the hierarchical data. I'd like to use CTE from SQL 2005.

```
WITH tree (id, parentid, code, name) AS
(
    SELECT id, ofs.ParentID, ofs.code, ofs.name
      FROM OrganizationFeatures ofs
     WHERE ofs.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ofs.id, ofs.ParentID, ofs.code, ofs.name
      FROM OrganizationFeatures ofs
      JOIN tree ON tree.ID = ofs.ParentID
)

select * from tree
```

But I'd like to sort by code and the result shold be as following:

```
1
1/1
1/1/1
1/1/2
1/2/1
1/2/2
2
4/1
```

etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

To get the concatenated values, you need to do it in the with.

To sort, you need to add an order by in the last select.

```
WITH tree (id, parentid, code, name) AS
(
    SELECT id, ofs.ParentID, ofs.code, ofs.name
      FROM OrganizationFeatures ofs
     WHERE ofs.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ofs.id, ofs.ParentID, tree.code+'/'+ofs.code, ofs.name
      FROM OrganizationFeatures ofs
      JOIN tree ON tree.ID = ofs.ParentID
)

select * from tree order by code
```

Also, if code is not a varchar, you will have to convert the code columns in this bit of code (`tree.code+'/'+ofs.code`) for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Loki, I had the similar query but it didn't sort by name as I wanted but by the code - it was Friday and I was overloaded.

Anyway, running your query gave me an error, it's necessary to cast; I had to change it following way:

```
WITH tree (id, parentid, name, code) AS
(
    SELECT id, ofs.ParentID, ofs.name, CAST(ofs.name as varchar(255))
      FROM OrganizationFeatures ofs
     WHERE ofs.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ofs.id, ofs.ParentID, ofs.name, CAST(tree.code+'/'+ofs.name as varchar(255))
      FROM OrganizationFeatures ofs
      JOIN tree ON tree.ID = ofs.ParentID
)

select * from tree order by code
```

The problem is that it's necessary to cast to a varchar despite of the fact that name is varchar. It's quite possible that varchar(255) isn't enough with large trees.

So I made a version where the above mention problem isn't so big:

```
WITH tree (id, parentid, name, code) AS
(
    SELECT id, ofs.ParentID, ofs.name, 
           CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ofs.name ASC) as varchar(255)) 
      FROM OrganizationFeatures ofs
     WHERE ofs.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ofs.id, ofs.ParentID, ofs.name, 
           CAST(tree.code +'/' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ofs.name ASC) as varchar(255)) as varchar(255))
      FROM OrganizationFeatures ofs
      JOIN tree ON tree.ID = ofs.ParentID
)

select * from tree order by code
```

But I don't like such solution where is necessary to cast. Is there any better solution?